# Configuring AWS Network Firewall for Domain-Based Filtering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, firewall

I'm currently managing an AWS environment with strict egress controls, where traffic is only permitted to specific IPs and ports. Our new requirement involves allowing outbound traffic to a domain (example.com), which looks as though it's hosted via CloudFront (adding the cloudfront prefix list to the egress security group won't fly)

I'm contemplating using AWS Network Firewall, as I understand it can handle domain name filtering. Additionally, the other features of Network Firewall are appealing compared to just using Route 53 Resolver DNS Firewall .

If I proceed with AWS Network Firewall, how should I adjust our current egress security group settings? For instance, would it be advisable to allow outbound traffic on required ports to 0.0.0.0/0, and then rely on Network Firewall for more granular domain-based/IP based filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the current outbound rules in the Security Groups will be set to 0.0.0.0/0. The egress network packet from source/client would be meant for the Internet and have an unpredictable IP address - the very reason FQDN/domain name based filtering solutions are needed. Therefore, we want the network packet to be able to leave the network interface (ENI in AWS) of the source at all. (Security Groups are attached to ENIs.) You could limit the protocol to TCP and the port, to say 443, if these parameters are fairly static, but it's not necessary unless lateral movement within the VPC to other open ports was also a concern.

Depending on how strictly your environment operates, you want to be aware that AWS Network Firewall can easily be bypassed by specifying an allowed domain name but any desirable IP, though. You can read more about that at [1].

From AWS' own documentation at [2]:

> For HTTPS traffic, Network Firewall uses the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension in the TLS handshake to determine the hostname, or domain name, that the client is trying to connect to. For HTTP traffic, Network Firewall uses the HTTP host header to get the name. In both cases, Network Firewall doesn't pause connections to do out-of-band DNS lookups. It uses the SNI or host header, not the IP addresses, when evaluating domain list rule groups. If you want to inspect IP addresses, to mitigate situations where the SNI or host headers have been manipulated, write separate rules for that and use them in conjunction with or in place of your domain list rules.

Besides the `wget` example in that blog post, `curl` can accomplish this too for exfiltration over HTTPS. Consider `api.github.com` is allowed and `1.1.1.1` (Cloudflare) isn't, the following command will go through:

`curl -v --connect-to "api.github.com:443:1.1.1.1:443" -k -H "Host: 1.1.1.1" https://api.github.com/`

[1] https://canglad.com/blog/2023/aws-network-firewall-egress-filtering-can-be-easily-bypassed/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/network-firewall/latest/developerguide/stateful-rule-groups-domain-names.html

*Disclosure: I'm an engineer on a competing product called DiscrimiNAT Firewall [3], so spend a lot of time testing various firewalls' claims & capabilities.*

[3] https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-7ulmdnoq5jnwu